# ANR error with Threads

Tags: android, process

Some users are getting (ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut) error with my app on line threadAudio.start()

```
private void startAudio(int audioId) {

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioId);

    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    });

    mPlayer.start();
    vSeek.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());

    threadAudio = new Thread(thread);
    threadAudio.start();
}

public Runnable thread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(mPlayer != null){
                int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = currentPosition;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        vSeek.setProgress(msg.what);
    }
};
```

First, i am not able to reproduce the error on my device! Can this be device-specific?

I am using handler as per android doc suggestion to avoid accessing the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread...

Or maybe I have to call threadAudio.stop() somewhere between the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to put `Thread.sleep(100);` inside your `while(mPlayer != null){` loop? Essentially your while loop is continuously sending armies upon armies of message to your handler, which runs on the UIThread, and this is what caused ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut error: all the CPU time are either spent processing those messages OR spent on sending those messages. Not a good place to be in :P

Comment: Try putting Thread.sleep(100); _within_ the while loop and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of a `never ending while loop` inside the Thread... you should find a better way to accomplish your task... Device with lower ram memory or devices with lot of Application's won't be able to make memory for such a code..

Comment: I need the seekbar to move with the duration of the played audio... and the while loop ends when the audio stops... any better solution?\